# Fail a test when certain condition met in cypress

Tags: cypress

I have the following method in a `utils.js`

```
/**
 * To verify the any array of objevt with given keyword
 * @param {*} list 
 * @param {*} searchKeyword 
 * @returns true if any mismatch found and vice versa
 */
export const verifyMatchedItems = (list, searchKeyword) => {
  var matchedItems = {
    title: [],
    region: [],
    country: [],
  };

  var nonMatchedItems = [];

  list.map((item, index) => {
    if (item.title.includes(searchKeyword)) {
      matchedItems.title.push(item.title);
    } else if (item.region.includes(searchKeyword)) {
      matchedItems.region.push(item.region);
    } else if (item.country.includes(searchKeyword)) {
      matchedItems.country.push(item.country);
    } else {
      nonMatchedItems.push(item);
    }
  });

  cy.log("Matched-Items:" + JSON.stringify(matchedItems));

  if (nonMatchedItems.length>0) {
    cy.log("nonMatchedItems:" + JSON.stringify(nonMatchedItems));
  }

  return nonMatchedItems.length>0;
};
```

And I am using it in `test` like this,

```
      //fetch all data in Search Results page and store it
      cy.getResultList().then((searchResultDetails) => {
        
        //verify the keyword is matched with result attributes
        var flag = Utils.verifyMatchedItems(searchResultDetails, searchKeyword);
        
        expect(flag).to.be.equal(false);
```

In case, the `flag` value is true then I want the test to fail. But when I try, it is failing but not executing any previous steps like `cy.log()`. How can we possibly make cypress to throw an error / fail a test with a customised message saying `Failed to due bla bla bla...`

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone want this, try to wrap the `expect()` in a `cy.then()`.

This is because the previous function contains some Cypress commands (only `cy.log()` in this case).

To make the final check after those commands, put it on the Cypress queue.

```js
//fetch all data in Search Results page and store it
cy.getResultList().then((searchResultDetails) => {
        
  //verify the keyword is matched with result attributes
  var flag = Utils.verifyMatchedItems(searchResultDetails, searchKeyword);
        
  cy.then(() => expect(flag).to.be.equal(false))
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `throw new error` and force a failure with custom message.

```js
throw new Error('The condition was not met!')
```

Comment: I tried the same earlier but it is not executing the previous cy.log commands.